# Is there a way in XPath to select an entire piece of an XML tree if one section of it meets certain criteria?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

So let's say I have some XML like this

```
<person>
     <person-id>ABC</person-id>
     <name>John Doe</name>
     <occupation>roofer</occupation>
     <address>
       <address>335 sample street</address>
       <city>joeville</city>
     </address>
</person>  
<person>
     <person-id>DEF</person-id>
     <name>Sam Doe</name>
     <occupation>XQuery Developer</occupation>
     <address>
       <address>234 XML street</address>
       <city>TestVille</city>
     </address>
</person> 
<person>
     <person-id>HIJ</person-id>
     <name>Jim Doe</name>
     <occupation>Sales</occupation>
     <address>
       <address>456 sample street</address>
       <city>TestVille</city>
     </address>
</person>
```

How can I select all person nodes for persons that live in the city 'TestVille' ?

```
person/address[city="TestVille"]
```

The above gets me the address nodes, but I need the whole person. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
person[address/city="TestVille"]
```

Comment: If there are 2 conditions how does the syntax look? (say city=TestVille and address ends in 'street')

Comment: `person[address[city="TestVille" and ends-with(address, 'street')]]`

Comment: @JoshKlein What version of XPath? XPath 1.0 doesn't have an `ends-with()` function, but there is a way to achieve the equivalent of `ends-with()`

Comment: You could try  `contains` , but then you should explicitly test the text node, as otherwise contains will check child nodes as well: `contains( address/text(), " street" )`